# Probibility extended response question

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I've been prepping for my end of year exams and I'm having difficulties answering this particular question. I don't recall the rules for these types of questions, any help with the solving methodology would be appreciated. Thanks!

**There are *n* identical black balls and *n* identical white balls. A blue box contains 3 black balls and *n*−3 white balls. A red box contains *n*−3 black balls and 3 white balls. A ball is taken at random from the red box and put in the blue box. A ball is then taken at random from the blue box.**

(A) Find the probability, in terms of *n*, that the ball taken from the blue box is:

i) black

ii) White

(B)
Find the probability, in terms of *n*
, that the first ball is black given that the second is white.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: A) Use law of total probability and condition on the outcome of the draw from the red box. B) use Bayes theorem

Answer (score 0):

We will use the phrases "$1^{\text{st}}$" and "$2^{\text{nd}}$" to mean, respectively, the ball being drawn from the red box (then put in the blue box) and the ball subsequently drawn from the blue box. [This is consistent with the phrasing of part (B) in the question.] Also, we'll use the obvious labels "$\text{B}$" and "$\text{W}$" for black and white.

(A) There are two possibilities: either $1^{\text{st}}$ is $\text{B}$, or $1^{\text{st}}$ is $\text{W}$. The probability that $1^{\text{st}}$ is $\text{B}$ is $\,\frac{n-3}{n},\,$ and in that case the probability that $2^{\text{nd}}$ is $\text{B}$ is $\,\frac{4}{n+1},\,$ and the probability that $2^{\text{nd}}$ is $\text{W}$ is $\,\frac{n-3}{n+1}.\,$ The computations will be similar for the cases when $1^{\text{st}}$ is $\text{W}$.

Then for (i) we have that

$$
\color{white}{text}\\
\begin{align}
P\;[2^{\text{nd}} \text{is B}]&=P\;[1^{\text{st}} \text{is B}\; \land \; 2^{\text{nd}} \text{ is B}] + P\;[1^{\text{st}} \text{is W} \land 2^{\text{nd}} \text{ is B}]\\[2ex]
&=\left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)\left(\frac{4}{n+1}\right)+ \quad...\\
\color{white}{text}
\end{align}
$$

Can you complete it from there? Part (ii) should be quite similar.

(B) This is asking for $\,P\;[1^{\text{st}} \text{is B} \mid 2^{\text{nd}} \text{ is W}].$ Using the formula $\,P\;[B \mid A] = \frac{P\;[B \land A]}{P\;[A]},\,$ we get

$$
\color{white}{text}\\
\begin{align}
P\;[1^{\text{st}} \text{is B} \mid 2^{\text{nd}} \text{ is W}] &= \frac{P\;[1^{\text{st}} \text{is B} \land 2^{\text{nd}} \text{ is W}]}{P\;[2^{\text{nd}} \text{ is W}]}\\[2ex]
&= \quad ...\\[2ex]
\color{white}{text}\\
\end{align}
$$

where both the numerator and denominator would already have been computed in part (A).